# HTML5 Media capture on mobile - video duration

Tags: ios, html, video, video-capture

I've implemented a mobile web page that allows users to record a video and upload to a server. I've used the HTML5 media capture input method:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
```

This launches the camera as expected and I can proceed through the upload process. However on iOS I can only record 1 minute of video footage.

When I've done something similar in a native app there is no limit to the length the recording.

Is this a limit set by default on iOS due to memory and is there any way to change this?

I've searched everywhere but can not find any information about iOS limiting the duration of a video recorded via a mobile web app.

Comment: What iOS device are you using?

Comment: See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/), `accept="video/*;capture=camcorder"` is not part of the spec/not supported anymore, use `<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture >` instead.   .

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with how much RAM is on your device and the video quality set in your device's **Photos & Camera** > **Record Video** settings. These are the options on an iPhone 6S (2G of RAM).

[image]

Higher quality video takes up more RAM/minute, at least until the video is uploaded to the web server.

Once recorded the video is compressed and uploaded. I've written [an article](https://blog.addpipe.com/video-quality-when-recording-videos-from-safari-on-ios-through-html-media-capture/) of how Safari on iOS compresses video when recording through HTML Media Capture.

PS: There is no way to specify a limit mentioned in the [HTML Media Capture Standard](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/).